# Lower_bound matching wrong strings

Tags: c++, struct, lower-bound

Now I am completely confused. I am googling all day and still can't get why this code doesn't work.

I have `vector` of `structs` and those `structs` have `string` property. When I want to add a new `struct` into `vector`, as first I have to check whether a `struct` with the same `string` property is already there. If it is, it won't be added.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

struct Try{
    string name;
    Try( string name) : name ( name ) { }
    bool                operator <                  ( const Try & a ) const
    {
        return name < a . name;
    }
};


int main(){

    vector<Try> vektor;
    Try *n;

    vektor . push_back( Try( "Prague" ) );

    n = new Try( "Brno" );


    vector<Try>::iterator it = lower_bound( vektor . begin(), vektor . end(), n -> name);

    if( it == vektor . end() ){
        cout << "not included" << endl;
        cout << it -> name << endl;
    }
    else
        cout << "included" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `vector<Try> vektor` - really?

Comment: What is the problem?  What did you learn when you debugged this?

Comment: it gives me `"not included"` `Prague`

Comment: Isn't that what you would expect?

Comment: You add "Prague" to the vector and then search for "Brno" which is not found. What did you expect would happen?

Comment: sorry guys, I have edited that.. now it is correct.. it is not included there so it has to return `vektor . end()`

Comment: You want `binary_search()` for that behavior instead of `lower_bound()`.

Comment: if it is included I need a position of that elements

Comment: You don't need `new` or pointers here.

Comment: I know man, but I need to know how to fix this.. if the string is included, I need its position.. when it isnt, I just need to know that it isnt there

Comment: Then you need to use `lower_bound()` and deal with the fact that the not found case can return a valid iterator to something that doesn't match or `end()`.  I agree that `binary_search()` might be more useful if it behaved that way - you can wrap this in your own variant of `binary_search()` (I'd give a different name though - maybe `binary_search_ex()`).

Comment: `lower_bound` returns the first element that is *not less than* the given key. In this case, checking "Brno" is less than "Prague", so the first element that is *not less than* "Brno" is "Prague". Notice that it doesn't return an iterator equal to `vektor.end()`. (ie. Your assumption that "it is not included there so it has to return `vektor . end()`" is wrong.)

Comment: P.S. Dereferencing an `XXX.end()` iterator is undefined behavior, so after checking `it == vektor.end()`, it is nonsense to call `it->name` because `end` doesn't point to a valid entry in your vector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this function that's a variation of the standard `binary_search()`.  It returns an iterator to the matching element (the 'lowest' one) if the value is found in the range, and an iterator equal to `last` (usually `end()`) when there's no match:

```
template< class ForwardIt, class T >
ForwardIt binary_search_ex(ForwardIt first, ForwardIt last, const T& value)
{
    ForwardIt it = std::lower_bound(first, last, value);

    if ((it != last) && (value < *it)) it = last;

    return it;
}
```