# finding the return value of the lower_bound

Tags: c++, lower-bound

I am trying to use a lower_bound  to find out if value is inside a vector of pointers to struct. I am using

```
auto it = lower_bound( myVector.begin() , myVector.end() , value , comparer() );
```

comparer function looks like

```
struct comparer
{
    bool operator ()(Property * ms, int const i) const
    {
        return ms -> ID  < i;
    };
};
```

and i want to check if the element with said ID was found. How can i check it?
I tried using

```
if( (*it) -> ID == value ) {
   return false;
}
```

but this is throwing segmentation fault, Is there any way how to check if element is already there?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36269410/12711 may help.

Answer (score 4):

If you just want to check **if** the object exists, use [`std::binary_search`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/binary_search):

```
bool exists = std::binary_search(myVector.begin(), myVector.end(), value, comparer());
```

That said, if you want the iterator, you'll need to not only check if the value matches but you'll also have to *first* check if you got something other than the end iterator:

```
auto it = std::lower_bound(myVector.begin(), myVector.end(), value, comparer());
if (it != myVector.end() && (*it)->ID == value) {
   return false;
}
```

If you do get `end()`, then that dereference is undefined behavior, which could manifest as a segmentation fault.